# How to resolve the conflict between 11.0.2 and 16.0 of guava when using yarn, spark and spark-cassandra-connector?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, hadoop-yarn, spark-cassandra-connector

my yarn's version is `hadop-2.4.0.x`, spark is `spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4` and spark-cassandra-connector is `spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.5.0-M2`, when I executed the following command:

```
bin/spark-shell --driver-class-path $(echo lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /:/g')  --master yarn-client 
--deploy-mode client --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=192.21.0.209 
--conf spark.cassandra.auth.username=username --conf spark.cassandra.auth.password=password --conf spark.sql.dialect=sql 
--jars lib/guava-16.0.jar,spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.5.0-M2.jar,lib/cassandra-driver-core-2.2.0-rc3.jar
```

After starting, I input the following scala under the prompt:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode}
import org.apache.spark.{Logging, SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, Days, LocalDate}
val cc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)

val rdd: DataFrame = cc.sql("select user_id,tag_models,dmp_province," +
"zp_gender,zp_age,zp_edu,stg_stage,zp_income,type " +
"from user_center.users_test")
```

I got the classic error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  
com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.withFallback
(Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback;
Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;)
Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
```

After search this error in `google` and `stackoverflower`, I know that the conflict between the different versions of `guava` caused this error, and found [hadoop 2.4](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/dependency-analysis.html) use `guava-11.0.2` but [spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.5.0-M2](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v1.5.0-M2/project/Versions.scala) use `guava-16.0.1`.

How to resolve this kind of error, any advice will be appreciated!

UPDATE

I am so sorry for testing long time!

Now, for spark-submit, I tested this resolution  [Making Hadoop 2.6 + Spark-Cassandra Driver Play Nice Together](http://arjon.es/2015/10/12/making-hadoop-2-dot-6-plus-spark-cassandra-driver-play-nice-together/) successfully under my test yarn cluster

Comment: My man, you are on the track. If you happen to found the answer please share it with us. I think the road is to shade at sbt assembly stage.

Comment: @msemelman I am sorry, I did not come here yesterday, Do you have the same issue?

Comment: @msemelman, I tested the approach as #user1314742 said, nothing changed!

Comment: @abelard2008 I added new comment to my answer, please try to the export mentioned in the comment.

Comment: @abelard2008 one more thing, in your answer is it `$(echo lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /:/g')` or you meant `$(ls lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /:/g')` ?

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?

Answer (score 3):

In Hadoop configuration, add the following property to your `hadoop-env.sh`

```
HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
```

In Spark configurations there is also a property you could set it to true `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst` , but it still an experimental and used only in cluster mode (have a look at the [spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)). Personally I have not tried this property but since it is presented in the documentation I thought it is worth to mention

Comment: It didn't work for me. Neither the env variable nor the the spark property.

Comment: That's weird... I ll try it one more time and tell you exactly how

Comment: @msemelman have you tried to do `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/PATH/TO/SPARK/CASSSANDRA/CONNECTER/JAR` before the `spark-shell` command ?