# guava jar conflict when using ElasticSearch on Spark job

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

so i have a piece of code which index records into elastic. This code is running with spark and hadoop.
I just upgraded Elasticsearch to 2.3.1.
When i'm running my code on the local machine it works great.
When i'm trying to run it with the spark submit job, i'm getting

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;

After searching google, i realized the problem is with guava, so in my pom.xml i just put the

com.google.guava
guava
19.0
under the dependencyManagement.

but the error stil happen, so i guess spark (1.6) is also using an older version of guava, but i can't find where and how to solve it...
i also tried to make a new jar which shade elastic-search 2.3.1 + com.google.common and use it, but didn't work also

Comment: spark 1.6 uses guava 14.0.1. Checkout that blog post: https://www.elastic.co/blog/to-shade-or-not-to-shade

Comment: You can solve it using guava `18.0` in your `pom.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is both elasticsearch and spark uses guava but different versions: es uses 18.0 and spark uses 14.0.

So in your pom.xml you can try to exclude the old version that spark uses:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Or uses methods that described in that blog post: https://www.elastic.co/blog/to-shade-or-not-to-shade

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed in [How to resolve the conflict between 11.0.2 and 16.0 of guava when using yarn, spark and spark-cassandra-connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36004072) is working perfectly. You just need to set the value of `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst` to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Use spark-submit options :

```
spark-submit --jars path_to/guava-18.0.jar,.. \
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=guava-18.0.jar \
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=guava-18.0.jar  \
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing exactly the same issue when submitting my job to spark cluster. @alpert second solution worked for me. I was using elastic search 2.4.0 client as my dependency, so i found alternative shaded jar for 2.4.0 :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-atlassian-shaded-1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same exact problem and I was able to solve this by adding "guava-16.0.1.jar" to "--addJars" property and by setting 
sparkConf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "guava-16.0.1.jar");
Since "spark.driver.extraClassPath" entries will prepend to the classpath of the driver, your uploaded guava.jar will override the hadoop's guava.jar.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("YarnResource").setMaster("yarn-cluster").set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "guava-16.0.1.jar");

List<String> argList = new ArrayList<>();
int argIndex = 0;
argList.add(argIndex++, "--addJars");
argList.add(argIndex++, "/home/myuser/myapp/lib/guava-16.0.1.jar"); 
String[] sparkArgArray = argList.toArray(new String[argList.size()]);
ClientArguments cArgs = new ClientArguments(sparkArgArray, sparkConf);
// create an instance of yarn Client client
Client client = new Client(cArgs, hadoopConfig, sparkConf);
```